# Selenium. Получение Cookie с сайта

Tags: c#, cookie, selenium

Я хотел бы узнать как с помощью `Selenium` получить `Cookie`, c браузера по умолчанию. То есть пользователь авторизуется на моем сайте, а потом скачивает клиент. Вот этот самый клиент получает Cookie с моего сайта после авторизации.

Comment: Селениум никакого отношения к этому делу не имеет. Если пользователь авторизовался на вашем сайте то он своим браузером пользовался а не вашим, для управления которым селеним и предназначен.

Comment: А без Silenium можно?

Comment: А клиент вы писали или это сторонняя программа?

Comment: Задумывается как клиент для __Моего__ сайта.

Comment: Непонятно зачем вам куки чужого человека...

Comment: Смотрите, человек авторизуется на сайте. Скачивает программу. И входит в личный кабинет (в приложении) используя cookie с сайта. Чтобы дважды не вводить логин и пароль.

Comment: @Wheelys использовать куки браузера пользователя в своем приложении нельзя, это же захват личных данных пользователя. Можно использовать собственные алгоритмы для определения пользователя с последующей автоматической авторизацией